# How to write if condition statement in ios metal shader?

Tags: ios, shader, metal

Can an if statement be too long or be too complex in Metal or OpenglES?
I am working on Metal in iOS now. I write an if statement looks like a little bit long, however there is no problem processed by cpu.
It looks like below.

```
if ((vector0.x * vector1.y == vector0.y * vector1.x) && (((point.x <= segment.x && point.x >= segment.z) || (point.x <= segment.z && point.x >= segment.x)) && ((point.y <= segment.y && point.y >= segment.w) || (point.y <= segment.w && point.y >= segment.y))))
```

I program stopped here.

```
[MetalGPU().gpuDevice newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:kernelFunction error:&error];
```

There is no error report, no crash, no error message, just no response.
My first idea is that it is too long that my statement is.
So I make it below.

```
bool isPointOnSegment(float2 point,float4 segment) {
    float2 vector0 = segment.xy - point;
    float2 vector1 = segment.zw - segment.xy;
    bool condition = vector0.x * vector1.y == vector0.y * vector1.x;
    condition = condition && ((point.x <= segment.x && point.x >= segment.z) || (point.x <= segment.z && point.x >= segment.x));
    condition = condition && ((point.y <= segment.y && point.y >= segment.w) || (point.y <= segment.w && point.y >= segment.y));
    if (condition) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However,it is still no response.
Then I made another change.

```
bool isPointOnSegment(float2 point,float4 segment) {
    float2 vector0 = segment.xy - point;
    float2 vector1 = segment.zw - segment.xy;
    bool condition = vector0.x * vector1.y == vector0.y * vector1.x;
    condition = true;
    condition = condition && ((point.x <= segment.x && point.x >= segment.z) || (point.x <= segment.z && point.x >= segment.x));
    condition = false;
    condition = condition && ((point.y <= segment.y && point.y >= segment.w) || (point.y <= segment.w && point.y >= segment.y));
    if (condition) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It worked.
I really do not know the difference between the two above.
Could you tell me is there something I must obey while writing metal shader if statement?
What's the reason that led to the problem above?

Comment: What do you mean "no response"? What did you expect to happen and what actually happened? Without more information, I don't think we can answer your question. Can you post the entire .metal program?

Comment: I was able to successfully create a compute pipeline object from a function that calls either of the first two variants of your function on an iPhone X running iOS 12.4. Can you specify which device and OS you're testing on?

Comment: @user1118321 It's just like blocking ui thread.I expect that program get a render resut,at least somethig show in console.However nothing get out,just blocking.I am afraid I can not show you the .metal ,it is business secret.

Comment: Not specified device,it is just a device that can run metal.@warrenm

Comment: Well I can't tell you what's wrong with first program you have above, but the second one is faster because the compiler can optimize away the entire thing. Because you set `condition` to false, and then do an `&&`, the result is always false, so there's no reason to do any work in the function. It can be replaced entirely with `return false;`.